# Java Loses International Characters in Stream

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am having trouble reading international characters in Java.

The default character set being used is UTF-8 and my Eclipse workspace is also set to this.

I am reading a title of a video from the Internet (Gangam Style in fact ;) ) which contains Korean characters, I am doing this as follows:

```
BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(shellCommand.getInputStream()));
String fileName = null, output = null;
while ((output = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
if (output.indexOf("Destination") > 0) {
    System.out.println(output);
```

I know that the title it will read is: "PSY - GANGNAM STYLE (강남스타일) M/V", but the console displays the following instead: "PSY - GANGNAM STYLE () M V" which causes errors further along in my program.

It seems like the InputStream Reader isn't reading these characters correctly.

Does anyone have any ideas? I've spent the last hour scouring the Internet and haven't found any answers. Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: @Satya Should I specify this encoding in the InputStreamReader or in the Eclipse workspace?

Comment: set in inputStreamReader

Comment: What is `shellCommand`? If you're reading from another process, it's entirely feasible that *that's* mangling things. If this is meant to be from a web site, why don't you fetch it directly?

Comment: @JonSkeet shellCommand is a method which gets information about the page, if I display the output, the characters are there as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The default character set being used is UTF-8

The default where? In Java itself, or in the video? It would be a *much* clearer if you specified this explicitly. You should check that's correct for the video data too.

> It seems like the InputStream Reader isn't reading these characters correctly.

Well, all we know is that the text isn't showing properly on the console. *Either* it isn't being read correctly, *or* it's not being displayed correctly. You should print out each character's Unicode value so you can check the exact content of the string. For example:

```
static void logCharacters(String text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        System.out.println(c + " " + Integer.toHexString(c));
    }
}
```

Comment: Java itself is set to UTF-8 as well as the video website's page. I'm unable to print out the Unicode value because the characters aren't there, there's no input between the (). I just realized that the '/' is also being stripped from the String.

Comment: @Crisitan: It's still much clearer if you specify it explicitly (in the `InputStreamReader` constructor call), and also if you dump the contents of the string. Additionally, it's not at all clear how you're getting the data in the first place - `shellCommand` doesn't fill me with confidence...

Comment: The output is as I thought: ( 28 ) 29, there's nothing in between.

Comment: I'm now specifying the charset in the constructor call, the output is still however the same.

Comment: @Cristian: Right - I wasn't suggesting your suspicion was incorrect - just that it helps to be absolutely sure. What the console *displays* isn't a good indication.

Comment: Does the fact that the '/' is also stripped from the video title indicate something else?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enure default char-set using `Charset.defaultCharset().name()` else use

```
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(shellCommand.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
```

I tried sample program and it prints correctly in eclipse. It might be problem of windows console as AlexR has pointed out.

```
byte[] bytes = "PSY - GANGNAM STYLE (강남스타일) M/V".getBytes();
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String str = bufferedReader.readLine();
    System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
 PSY - GANGNAM STYLE (강남스타일) M/V
```

Comment: I have tried this and the output is the same - the characters are stripped.

Comment: The problem happens when you are printing your characters to console. Windows OS does not support UTF8 in command prompt by default. Try to see that values using debugger or print them to file opened using UTF8.

Comment: @AlexR a file is saved to disk with the same title and the filename contains the special characters. However in my program the filename is stored as a String and that string isn't storing these characters.

Comment: @AmitD It's possible that because you're reading in bytes that this can be achieved, however I need to get an InputStream to get the output of the program.

Comment: @AlexR Also I'm using Mac so I don't think it's an issue with Windows.